# How to add a clickable button to the group header?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

We are able to customize the group header title by using `groupHeader: function(){ //code here }`.

Any idea how do we add a clickable button to the group header? For now button is clickable but how do we fire an event once the button is clicked?

```
// Tabulator
...
groupHeader: groupHeaderFormatter,

// Function
function groupHeaderFormatter(value, count, data, group) {
   let code = `<span id="valueText">${value}</span><button class="btn btn-link" id="btn"><i class="far fa-star"></i>`
   return code;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Search this link of the documentation for the `groupClick` callback.  I think it will do what you need.  http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can register an onclick handler just as you would normally in HTML:

```
<button onclick="myFunction"></button>
```

Calls `myFunction` when user clicks the button.

```
function groupHeaderButtonClicked() {
    alert("You clicked the button.")
}

// Function
function groupHeaderFormatter(value, count, data, group) {
    return `<span id="valueText">${value}</span><button onclick="groupHeaderButtonClicked" class="btn btn-link" id="btn"><i class="far fa-star"></i></button>`
}
```

*Don't forget to close `<button>`.*